# How can I display a plot in sidebarPanel without blank area?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny

I have two problems to be solved. To begin, the model is not running i dont know  why?

DONE!by Vongo and NicE. First problem is: I have two locations and their sales quantity that is displayed as plot. I would like to change the plot title according to select input like ggtitle("Analyze of input$location").

Secondly, I would like to display the plot in sidebarPanel - below the execute buton-. However, at the exercises I had a white blank area which has already booked for plots to be produced. Before executing plot, i dont want to have this booked area in sidebarPanel.

[image]

```
ui.r

library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Sidebar Study"),
sidebarPanel(

selectInput(inputId = "location",label = "Choose Location",
            choices = c('Los Angeles', 'New York', selected = "Los Angeles"),

actionButton("execute","Execute")
plotOutput("plot"))),
  mainPanel( )))


server.r

library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
  if(input$execute){
  if(input$location="New York"){
  tmp <- data.frame(time = 1:100, sales = round(runif(100, 150, 879)) )
  }
  if(input$location="Los Angeles"){
    tmp <- data.frame(time = 1:100, sales = round(runif(100, 90, 512)) ) }
  y<-ggplot(as.data.frame(tmp), aes(time)) +  geom_line(size=1,aes(y=sales, colour = "sales"))+ ggtitle(paste("Analyze of", input$location))
  y
}})
})
```

Comment: For your first problem, I just read very quickly, but what about `ggtitle(paste("Analyze of",input$location))` ?
(maybe I read too fast)

Comment: yes you are right thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `renderUi` and `uiOutput` to dynamically add the holder for the plot when the user clicks the button. In your ui.R, try replacing `plotOutput("plot")` by `uiOutput("plotDiv")` and in the server.R you could add:

```
output$plotDiv <- renderUI({
    if(input$execute>0){
    plotOutput("plot")
    }
  })
```

For the title of the plot, you could do:

```
ggtitle(paste("Analyze of",input$location))
```

Also you have issues with the `if` in the `server.R`, it should be `input$location=="New York"` (add an equal sign). You also have parenthesis issues in your `ui.R`,right now the action button and the plot output are in the selectInput.